# too many values to unpack (expected 2) in XLNet model

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, torch

---

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[5], line 2
1 # Get the model predictions
----> 2 start_logits, end_logits = model(**inputs)

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that your model function returns only one value (or a tuple with only one element), whereas you expect a tuple with two elements (namely: (start_logits, end_logits)). You have to check what the output of 'model' is and be sure that it returns a tuple with two elements.